# The connection was reset on laravel 5 login or register page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

i am using laravel 5.1 authentication on my development server its work fine but on my production server both login and register pages give error The connection was reset, as there is no php/ laravel error not able to figure out where is the problem.

Comment: provide your global php error handler located at /var/log/nginx|apache2 or you can use ``artisan serve`` and check if it returns an error, double check  your session if it is a ``file`` also check your ``storage folder`` if it has the right permission to write sessions files

Comment: found the problem, i was using blade comments in view, on development server no problem but on production server blade comment was creating problem, after removing its work fine

Answer (score 1):

The one cause for this is laravel blade comments. Try to remove blade comments from that pages and check. Other wise try following scenario which I faced.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and site suddenly started giving "Connection was reset" and "No data received" error. I was facing issue in whole site.

After digging the issue, I came to following solution:
Add following code into your root `.htaccess` and issue will be fixed for now

```
php_flag xcache.cacher Off
php_flag xcache.size 0
php_flag xcache.stat Off
```

Hope this helps you too.